# Convert Array Athena into String

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I currently have a JSON output as an array in Athena:

This is the query Im running

```
WITH dataset AS (SELECT
Items
FROM
(SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(message, '$.items') AS Items
   FROM kafka.database
   )))
select * from dataset
LIMIT 10
```

And this is the current Ouput

```
["item0","item1","item2","item3"]
```

But would like to generate the Ouput from AWS Athena in this way:

```
"item0,item1,item2,item3"
```

I have tried to follow this steps from Athena documentation but it's not working:

```
WITH dataset AS (SELECT
Items
FROM
(SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    array_join(JSON_EXTRACT(message, '$.items'),' ') AS Items
   FROM kafka.database
   )))
select * from dataset
LIMIT 10
```

But for example, in this way, I am able to select the first Item in the JSON output.

```
WITH dataset AS (SELECT
Items
FROM
(SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    json_array_get(JSON_EXTRACT(message, '$.items'),0) AS Items
   FROM kafka.database
   )))
select * from dataset
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?!! provide error message if you get one

Comment: Yes, this is the error. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 6:5: Unexpected parameters (json, varchar(1)) for function array_join. Expected: array_join(array(T), varchar) T, array_join(array(T), varchar, varchar) T

Comment: clearly from error message you are passing a json to `array_join` instead of an array

Comment: So in this case how can I convert the JSON to a string?

Comment: provide more detail , provide right details ( like your data , data types , etc)

Comment: Thanks , I already updated the current query and data structure.

Comment: what's the output of `JSON_EXTRACT(message, '$.items')`  ?

Comment: This is the output  - ["item0","item1","item2","item3"]

Comment: are you sure ? isn't like this : `[{"item0","item1","item2","item3"}]` ??

Comment: Yes, the current output does not contain `{}`

Comment: @eshirvana `[{"item0","item1","item2","item3"}]` is not a valid json, so it can't be output of `json_extract`.

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?highlight=json_array_get#json_extract) does not return an `array`, it returns value of `json` type, so directly manipulating it as an array is not supported. One way to handle it is to cast it to `array(varchar)` and use `array_join` on it:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (json_arr) AS (
   VALUES (json '["item0","item1","item2","item3"]')
)

-- query
select array_join(cast(json_arr as array(varchar)), ', ')
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| item0, item1, item2, item3 |